Como configurar Nginx como proxy reverso
Como puedo hacer para que el servidor nginx haga lo siguiente que mediante una solicitu del navegador http://ip_nginx/sitio1 haga la solicitud hacia nginx y este redirija hacia apache y este muestra la pagina de incio. Pero debo hacer esto http://ip_nginx/sitio1  y si hago sitio2 me envie a otra pagina. 

Parte importante de la cultura del sitio es que al publicar una pregunta se muestre un esfuerzo por parte del autor al incluir el código que ha intentado o lo que ha investigado ya que en este sitio no hacemos tareas/proyectos/trabajos. Lecturas recomendadas: [ask] y [mcve]. Por favor oprime [edit] y agrega lo que has intentado o haz una pregunta específica sobre un error o problema que tienes para implementar TU solución a la tarea/proyecto.

Por favor no publiques código o mensajes de error/trazas de pila en imágenes, publica directamente el texto del código, el texto de los errores y los stack traces. Esto hace que sea menos complicado, para quien quiera ayudarte, investigar sobre el tema y hacer sus propias pruebas/adaptaciones al código, al escribir una respuesta y de esa forma aumenta tus posibilidades de encontrar la ayuda que buscas. Un saludo.
